# COUNTIFs or ArrayFormula with partial text, but wildcards might show false positives

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I've got a Google Sheet with some demographic data and I'm trying to do counts of how many people marked a particular gender identifier. The options are Man, Woman, Non-binary, Other, I do not wish to disclose, and blank. The column that has this information has options separated by commas.

Right now our formula doesn't account for people that marked more than one option (e.g. "Non-binary, other"). I saw that wildcards are possible; however, I'm concerned about "Man" and "Woman", because it seems like wildcards will mark one as the other (for instance, "*Man*" would find people who marked "Man" and "Other", but also any instance of "Woman").

Is there a way to do more fine-tuned formulae so that searches for "Man" doesn't count "woman" but will count things like "man, other"?

I just looked up the SPLIT() function, but I'm unclear on how to have it work with COUNTIFs.

As an example:
=COUNTIFS(subscribed!$AB:$AB,"<=30/6/2022", subscribed!$Z:$Z,"Non-binary")
doesn't show anyone who marked "Non-binary, other"

Comment: Can you post few dummy data (like real data but fake, structure should same as real case) so that we can understand your requirement clearly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try-

```
=ROWS(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A=DATE(2022,6,30),MAP(B2:B,LAMBDA(x,OR(INDEX(SPLIT(x,", ",FALSE)=D2))))))
```

Or using `COUNTIFS()`.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,DATE(2022,6,30),MAP(B:B,LAMBDA(x,OR(INDEX(SPLIT(x,", ",FALSE)=D2)))),TRUE)
```

[image]